# Python - using regex to catch a numerical value in a string

Tags: python, regex

I have a piece of code to try to pull out a numerical value, in this case 'rel' from within a string like this:

```
str1 = 'span class="stars" rel="3.2" style="width:64.0%" title="Rating 3.2 out of 5 stars">/span>'

match = re.findall(r'span rel="(\d+)*(\.\d+)".\*>/span>', str1)

if match:
    print("it's here!")          
else:
    print("not found")
```

However, it does not work. Does anyone know the adjustments I'd need to do get it right?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably looking for this

```
str1 = 'span class="stars" rel="3.2" style="width:64.0%" title="Rating 3.2 out of 5 stars">/span>'

match = re.findall(r'span.*?rel="(\d+)(\.\d+)".*>/span>', str1)

print (match)
```

Main reason why you're not finding anything is because your regex needs to have `rel` immediately after span, which your `str1` doesn't follow. Adding a `.*?` in between span and rel will non-greedily capture everything else

Comment: Hi Lau, sorry it took me so long to get back to you. Your solution definitely works, but I found out that doing


match = re.findall(r'[<span.*rel=\"](\d+\.\d+)[\"]', str1)


instead puts it in a more suitable format for me.

Thanks a bunch.